# Is there a way in AngularJs to test controllers with Services and only mock\stub things like $http?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'd like to test from my controller down through my various services and back and only stub the data that is being returned from calls to $http.

This is an approach I use in C# with IoC containers where I only override the dependencies that you want to stub for the test and leave everything else as is.

Is there a way to do this in AngularJs tests with Jasmine so that I can increase the scope of my tests to be greater than a single controller or service?

**Edit**

Below is an example to clarify the approach I want to use.

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('aController', [
        'servcieB',
        'serviceC',
        function ($scope, serviceB, serviceC) {

            serviceC.doHttpSomething().then(function (result) {

                    $scope.bSomething = serviceB.doSomething(result);
            });

        }
    ])
    .service('serviceB', function () {

        function doSomething(input) {

            return input + ' with something';
        };

        return {
            doSomething: doSomething
        }
    })
    .service('serviceC', [
        '$http',
        function (http) {

            function doHttpSomething() {
                return http.get('/something');
            };

            return {
                doHttpSomething: doHttpSomething
            }
        }]);
```

In the contrived code above I'd like to be able to write one test that tests aController, serviceB and serviceC while only mocks $http. On the $http mock I'd want to verify that serviceC called it correctly and then be able to return dummy data that I can then verify was processed correctly by serviceB and set correctly to the scope by aController by only checking that the expected result on $scope.bSomething is correct.

I know how to test each component separately in isolation but I want to test them all together as I want to write fewer tests and only want to verify that the overall desired behavior is correct. In c# this approach allows me to change the implementation details without having to rewrite a bunch of tests and I'd like to accomplish the same workflow here if possible.

**Edit 2 - Working solution below**
Based on William's feedback I created a FiddleJs with a working example that models my situation of having 2 layers of services (Domain and DAL) and only mocking the $http in the DAL services.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RyanVice/k6rtv2a8/12/)

//--- Js CODE --------------------------

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope, $log, BlogService) {
    $scope.username = 'Bret';
    $scope.posts = [];

    BlogService.getPostByUserName($scope.username).then(

    function (response) {

        $log.debug('MainController.getPostByUserName reponse.length: ' + response.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            $scope.posts.push(response[i]);
        }
    });
})
    .factory('BlogService', function ($q, $log, PostService, UserService) {

    function getPostByUserName(userName) {
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        UserService.getUserByUserName(userName).then(

        function (user) {

            $log.debug('BlogService.getUserByUserName.then user:' + user + ' user.id: ' + user.id);

            PostService.getPosts().then(

            function (posts) {
                var postsByUser = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                    if (posts[i].userId === user.id) {
                        postsByUser.push(posts[i]);
                    }
                }

                deffered.resolve(postsByUser);
            },

            function (error) {
                deffered.reject(error);
            });
        });

        return deffered.promise;
    };

    return {
        getPostByUserName: getPostByUserName
    };
})
    .factory('PostService', function ($http, $q) {

    function getPosts() {
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .success(function (response) {
            deffered.resolve(response);
        })
            .error(function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deffered.promise;
    };

    return {
        getPosts: getPosts
    };
})
    .factory('UserService', function ($http, $q) {

    function getUserByUserName(userName) {
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .success(function (response) {

            var user;

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                if (response[i].username === userName) {
                    user = response[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            deffered.resolve(user);
        })
            .error(function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deffered.promise;
    };

    return {
        getUserByUserName: getUserByUserName
    };
});


//--- SPECS -------------------------
describe('app', function () {

    var endpointController;

    var dummyPosts = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }];

    var dummyUsers = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }];

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    it('should return posts by bret ', inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();  

 $httpBackend.expectGET('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .respond(dummyUsers);
        $httpBackend.expectGET('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .respond(dummyPosts);    

        endpointController = $controller("MainController", { $scope: scope });

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(endpointController).not.toBeNull();
        expect(scope.posts.length).toBe(1);
    }));
});
```

To make the example live you can use the view code below

// -- HTML Code -----------------------

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">{{ "Hellow " + message }}
    <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">{{ post.title }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The fact that you need to do this is a bad smell.  This indicates that your services and controller are too tightly coupled.  You should be able to do meaningful unit testing on each component separately. What you are describing is a different kind of testing that is higher level.  This kind of testing is good to do, but it should be in conjunction with unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). It lets you specify responses for specific requests.

**Updates**

Use `angular.mock.inject` to go through the usual injection process. You'll need to explicitly wire up the scope:

```
    var ctrl; //controller under test
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, serviceB, serviceC) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new;
        ctrl = $controller('RatioBoxController', {
                $scope: scope,
                serviceB: serviceB,
                serviceC: serviceC,
            }
        );
    }));
```

You can use spies to verify methods on `serviceB` or `serviceC` were called, or the normal checks provided by `$httpBackend`.

Comment: I'm using $httpBackend for mocking $http, that's not the challenge I'm facing. The challenge is not having all the other services be mocks. I've added an example above to clarify.

Comment: Thanks William for your continued help with this but I'm not wanting ServiceB and ServiceC to be fakes (mocks or stubs). I'm wanting them to be the real classes pulled form the IoC in the same way they would in the live environment. The only thing I want to be a fake in this scenario is $http.

Comment: The objects injected ($rootScope, $controller, serviceB, serviceC) by angular.mock.inject will be the real objects. See [angular.mock.inject docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) for an example.

Comment: Thanks William! I'm going to verify this on my end and then update status of your response appropriately.

Comment: William, you are the man! That totally worked. I updated above to share a complex working example.